# Running URL via autohotkey redirects to blank login page even though user is already logged in

Tags: autohotkey

I've made a script that runs a work related webpage if it's not currently present. If it is present, it simply activates the window/tab. Works great on my PC. Here's the code.

```
DetectHiddenWindows, On
IfWinExist, Job Home - Internet Explorer
WinActivate, Job Home - Internet Explorer
else
Run, iexplore.exe https://oursite.com/jobhome.aspx
sleep 50
exitapp
```

Again, works great on my PC, but I decided to share it with my coworkers to help them out. Well, so far, it only works properly for one of them.

Here's how it's working improperly- when the script does the `Run, iexplore.exe https://oursite.com/jobhome.aspx` the site redirects to them to log in, *even though they are already logged in*. And on top of that, the credentials that are normally saved and autofilled by IE, are *missing completely*. It's incredibly infuriating and I've yet to pin down the issue.

Additionally, when they are greeted with that login page, they're able to manually go to the site in the same window and it loads without asking for credentials. Makes no sense!

I've also tried comobject to load IE and the same issue occurs.
I'm suspecting this is an IE issue rather than a script issue but I'm not certain.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're launching a new instance of iexplorer.exe ever time the script executes. Try the code below.

```
DetectHiddenWindows, On
IfWinExist, Job Home - Internet Explorer
WinActivate, Job Home - Internet Explorer
else
Run, https://oursite.com/jobhome.aspx
exitapp
```

Comment: Sadly, it's still ignoring my existing IE session and asking me to login again.